# Facebook Graph Api subscription to posts/notes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get updates on posts by users of my facebook app. I am interested in comments and likes on those posts and a way to get notified so that my app database can be populated.

I have seen [subscription](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime/) api but it is currently limmited to user/permission/pages. I am interested in connections. What work arounds do you guys suggest to get those updates and reaching those interactions. I understand that a cron job calling all posts individually using graph api is not practical.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking to solve a similar problem, i found the real-time updates feature to be a bit lacking in the data it returns (hopefully that changes). So i eneded up using Batch Request instead http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/ This allows you to do up to 20 graph api calls in one http request. However i'm a bit unsure on API usage. At the moment i'm assuming each API call in the batch still counts, as i cant find anything that says otherwise.